# Border background binding works only once

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a border with background binded to the color property in my ViewModel. But background change color only once after initialization. At the same time, I have 3 textboxes binded to the same property(R, G and B) and they works fine.

Why is textboxes works fine and border not? Here is border's code:

```
<Border x:Name="bNewColor" BorderBrush="Black" >
    <Border.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding NewColor}"/>
    </Border.Background>    
</Border>
```

Textboxes:

```
<Ellipse x:Name="eMarker" Margin="{Binding MarkerMargin, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="6" Height="6"/>
<TextBox x:Name="tbColorR" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding NewColor.R}"/>
```

VM:

```
class ViewModel
{
    Palette _palette
    Thickness _markerMargin;

    public Thickness MarkerMargin
    {
        get { return _markerMargin; }
        set
        {
            _markerMargin = value;
            _palette.DeterminateColorInPoint((int)_markerMargin.Left, (int)_markerMargin.Top);
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        _palette = new Palette();
    }

...
}
```

Palette class:

```
class Palette
{
   Color[,] _paletteColors;
   Color _newColor;
   public Color NewColor
   {
       get { return _newColor; }
       set
       {
           _newColor = value;
           OnPropertyChanged();
       }
   }

    public void DeterminateColorInPoint(int x, int y)
    {
        _newColor = _paletteColors[x, y];
    }

...
}
```

Comment: It is impossible to say why your code doesn't work without seeing [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. In the meantime, look at the debug output...often binding issues are caused by actual errors during binding, and these will show up in the debug output for the program.

Comment: I can't see how do you change the `NewColor`

Comment: Most probably you are trying to modify R, G, B components from your text boxes, which will not work the way you bind them.

Comment: No, I don't modify textboxes directly. They change value only then changed NewColor

Answer (score 2):

As I can see your DeterminateColorInPoint(int x, int y) method doesn't raise the 
OnPropertyChanged() of a NewColor property, thus XAML won't never know that the NewColor was changed. You have to change NewColor directly and not by its backing field like this `NewColor = _paletteColors[x, y];`.

give me to know if i was helped.
regards,